# Twitter4j crashes in Android 4

Tags: java, android, twitter4j

I'm trying to use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/) for Oauth process. I checked android browser that internet connection persists with opening Google.

I run following code snippet. When I run this code inside my activity I get "Unfortunately myapp is closed" in my emulator page. Inside Logcat I only see: "ccc: trying1". I don't see "trying2".

Possibly this error doesn't because of twitter4j, but I couldn't find the error.

```
    Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("12345", "aaaa1212");
    RequestToken requestToken = null;
    try {
         Log.d("ccc","trying1");
         requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
         Log.d("ccc","trying2");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        Log.d("unsuccess message:",e.getMessage());
        Log.d("unsuccess statuscode:", Integer.toString(e.getStatusCode()));
        Log.d("unsuccess errormessage:",e.getErrorMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Application:
minSdkVersion="10"
targetSdkVersion="17"
Emulator version Android 4.2.2

Also related:
[Twitter4j getOAuthRequestToken() with callback URL fails on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251843/twitter4j-getoauthrequesttoken-with-callback-url-fails-on-android)

Edit: I'm curious that not-async request can be the problem. Because same code works perfectly for Android 2.3.3.

Edit2: I get `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Logcat entries like this:

```
07-24 23:29:40.190    5455-5455/com.myexample.android  D/ccc: trying1
07-24 23:29:40.520    5455-5455/com.myexample.android  D/AndroidRuntime:      Shutting down VM
07-24 23:29:40.535    5455-5455/com.myexample.android  W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4db7908)
07-24 23:29:40.660    5455-5455/com.myexample.android  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        Unable to start activity               
         ComponentInfo{com.myexample.android/com.myexample.android.MyActivity}: 
         android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:150)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:122)
    at twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthRequestToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:104)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:281)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(TwitterBaseImpl.java:273)
    at com.myexample.android.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have the internet permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Yes I have that permission inside my manifest file.

Comment: Could you post your whole stacktrace of the crash? You must have it cause the app crashed ;)

Comment: As of Honeycomb you cannot perform network operations on the UI thread, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166).

Answer (score 2):

You exception name says it all 'NetworkOnMainThreadException'

You are making an network call on the main/UI thread.

Try executing this code in a seperate thread or ASyncTask like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    // your code
}).start();
```

Edit: Android 2.3 doesn't check if you do internet access on the main thread (therefor we all need to leave this version of Android behind ;) )